# Tutorial from http://nehe.gamedev.net/ , is programmable pipeline?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

OpenGL tutorial from http://nehe.gamedev.net/ is interesting , but I want to learn openGL ES 2.0 I mean programmable pipeline , please can any one say me is it Programmable pipeline tutorial or fixed line.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all of the tutorials marked *Legacy Tutorials* (which looks to be about 95% of the content), are all fixed pipeline tutorials. I'd suggest looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the replay i was just browsing net , one of them is  re writing those tutorials in to OpenGL ES 2.0 here is the link this might help others http://cmgresearch.blogspot.in/2010/09/nehe-opengl-tutorials-1-6-ported-to.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to that,

You can quite easily identify fixed function OpenGL code, by looking for Matrix manipulation APIs. Eg: glPushMatrix, glIdentity, glRotate etc.

The mentioned set of tutorials do use these APIs.